# Create Tab dynamically and load tab content using jqueryui

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

I am playing this [Jqueryui Tab Manipulation](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/manipulation.html) but I could not modify it the way I want it to work. I have menu like

```
<li onclick="createTab('Title','home.php')">Home</li>
<li onclick="createTab('Title','edit.php')">Edit</li>
<li onclick="createTab('Title','view.php')">View</li>
<div id="tabs">    
<div id="#tabs-1">
<ul>
   <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab Title here</a>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="tabs-1">tab content will be here</div>
</div>
```

The Jqueryui function I am working so far:

```
function creatTab(Title, url, e=null) {
       e.preventDefault();
            var label = Title.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
                id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
                li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
                var tabContentHtml = load(url) || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";

            tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
            tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
            tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
            tabCounter++;
        }
```

and I want to dynamically create tab and load edit.php in the newly created tab content area when a user clicks on Edit menu and so on. In the tab manipulation demo, instead of loading content, it uses dialogue. I am looking for solution in Google for quite a long hours but could not find it except some library like jquery easyui offers [simple solution](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/layout/tabs2_demo.html). This does not help as I have already decided to use jqueryui for my project. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Function name as follows is missing an 'e'

function creatTab